# cgi escape adding plus sign between ampersand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cgi, uri

I'm using `CGI::escape`, however it's adding the `+` sign between the `&` symbol. This is used for display in an email.

For example: Tom & Jerry. It returns Tom+&+Jerry. `fb_em_share_subject` is a column in the database

```
def email_share_subject
  "#{CGI::escape fb_em_share_subject}"
end
```

In rails console

```
s = "Tom & Jerry"
"Tom & Jerry"

CGI::escape s
"Tom+%26+Jerry"
```

Comment: It's not adding `+` because of `&` symbol. It's adding it because of space character. CGI escape replaces space with `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the `Util` class has a `url_encode` method.

```
ERB::Util.url_encode "Tom & Jerry"
"Tom%20%26%20Jerry"
```